# Prove that $\langle X,Y\rangle:= \mathbb{E}[XY] $ makes $\mathcal{H}$ into a real inner product space

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces, expected-value, inner-products

[image]

[**This is a question from the public notes,Page3**](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eee126/sp18/projection.pdf)

Prove that $\langle X,Y\rangle:= \mathbb{E}[XY] $ makes $\mathcal{H}$ into a real inner product space

$$\mathcal{H}:=\{X:X\, \text{is a real-valued random variable with}\,\mathbb{E}[X^2]<\infty\}$$

**Q1**. I know how to prove the Cauchy inequality, but I don't know how does *Cauchy hint* related to this question

**Q2** I think $\langle X,Y\rangle=Cov(X,Y)$ also make $\mathcal{H}$ into a real inner product?

**Q3** Here is how I approach this question for proving vector space, is this valid?

$$X,Y\in\mathcal{H}\,\text{so that}\,\mathbb{E}[X^2]<\infty,\mathbb{E}[Y^2]<\infty\\(X-Y)^2\geq0\\XY\leq2XY\leq X^2+Y^2\\2\mathbb{E}[XY]\leq\mathbb{E}[X^2]+\mathbb{E}[Y^2]<\infty\\
\mathbb{E}[X^2]+2\mathbb{E}[XY]+\mathbb{E}[Y^2]<\infty\quad \text{finite plus finite is finite}\\\mathbb{E}[(X+Y)^2]<\infty\implies (X+Y)\in\mathcal{H}$$

Regarding closed under multiplication, the argument is similar, finite times finite is also finite for any $X\in\mathcal{H}$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$

Appreciate for any comment and help for those *three questions*

---

**re-edit:**

$$\require{cancel}\xcancel{XY\leq}\left|2XY\right|\leq X^2+Y^2$$

Comment: For Q1 I agree with you. Proving that $\mathcal{H}$ is a vector space is normally done using Minkowski's inequality. The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is instead used to prove that the expectation $\mathbb{E}[XY]$ exists, i.e. that $\mathbb{E}[|XY|]<\infty$.

Comment: $XY \leq 2XY$ is wrong. But your proof of $X+Y \in \mathcal H$ works if you use $|XY| \leq 2|XY| \leq X^{2}+Y^{2}$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: C-S inequality is usually used to prove that $E|XY| <\infty$ but your argument (with the changes sugggested in my comment above) allows you to avoid C-S inequality.
Q2: No, $cov(X,Y)$ does not work because $cov (1,1)=0$. You need $ \langle X, X \rangle=0$ implies $X=0$ for $ \langle .,  .\rangle$ to be an inner product.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am thinking to avoid absolute value. if I only keep $2XY<X^2+Y^2$ is sufficient and deleting the left-most inequality is sufficient?

Comment: There is one problem still. $XY \leq X^{2}+Y^{2}$ does not guarantee that $EXY$ exists, but  $|XY| \leq X^{2}+Y^{2}$ does guarantee that $EXY$ exists. @LJNG

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is that the sense of also requiring to be bounded below? Why does it have to be bounded to guarantee the expectation exists?

Comment: You have to consider large negative values of $XY$ also. @ LJNG